# M-estimators: textbook examples

Tags: estimation, references, m-estimation

I would like to practice with solving M-estimators problems, but I cannot find where they are easily explained. Could you please recommend me something?

Comment: You mean solving by *hand*?

Comment: Yes, in ideal case I need some examples with solutions, but without solutions will also be fine

Comment: Would MLE examples be good?

Comment: No, MLE goes fairly easy for me, but not M-estimators

Comment: but MLE is a type of M estimator as is OLS, hence my comment (your question needs to be more precise)

Comment: Yes, I need more problems like OLS, where you have these estimating equations. In MLE it's different, because there is a likelihood, you take a derivative and so on..

Answer (score 3):

I found two sources:

1. [Essential Statistical Inference](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-4818-1). With this book, chapter 7, you see an introduction to M-estimation with some (not difficult examples). At the end of the chapter, there are some (not many) exercise where you can calculate something by hand.
2. [Asymptotic Statistics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/asymptotic-statistics/A3C7DAD3F7E66A1FA60E9C8FE132EE1D). In this book, chapter 5, which I am reading now, there are some examples and exercises (at the end).